Show that conditional residual extropy $r(X,Y)=0$ when random variable $Y$ is a function of $X$
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. Then a measure called conditional residual extropy, defined as
$$J(X|Y)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \bar{F}^2(x|y)dx, \hspace{2mm}y>0$$ where $\bar{F}_{X|Y}(x\mid y)=P(X>x\mid Y>y).$
Define $$r(X,Y)=1-\frac{J(Y|X)}{J(Y)},$$
where $J(Y)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty \bar{F}^2(y)dy,$ $\bar{F}(x)=P(X>x)$. $\bar{F}$ is the survival function.
Proposition: Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonnegative absolutely continuous random variables. Then
$$r(X,Y)=\begin{cases}0& X\text{ and }Y\text{are independent},\\
1&Y\text{ is a function of }X.
\end{cases}$$
I want to prove this proposition (link of the paper is given here please see the paper for more information. I want to prove proposition 6). When $X$ and $Y$ are independent it is easy to show that $r(X,Y)=0$. I am having problem with how to show that $r(X,Y)=1$ when $Y$ is a function of $X$. Did the author miss to assume something here?

The definition of conditional residual entropy in the title  of your question  is different from the definition of conditional residual entropy in the second sentence of the text of your question. Which one is it? Also, what is $J(Y)$? and why aren't you defining it since that is what is used in the displayed equation for $r(X,Y)$?

You might find a simplification to be helpful: because $\bar F^2$ is a survival function if and only if $\bar F$ is a survival function, you can drop the square.  Now, the integral of $\bar F$ for a non-negative random variable is its expectation.  This leads directly to a proof in such cases. Are you sure this result is correct, or even makes sense, for general random variables?

I don't think it is correct in general sense.

@Dilip Sarwate Please note that it is 'extropy' not 'entropy'.
